# Import a template from a zip file

Tags: templates, import

I am trying to use the AIAA template in Texstudio, however I do not know how. I have been using ShareLatex for the past year now and would like to start using Texstudio. So how do I take the downloaded zip folder and use the template? Each time I open the femplate file to the editor, it will not compile and I have no idea why.

Comment: You need to unpack the zip file, either by double clicking on it or using `unzip`.  You will then get a directory containing the template and related files.  It is the template in this directory that you should open.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while Texstudio can load files from a `zip`, it can't write to it. Therefore it cannot create the files it needs to compile your document, and has nowhere to put its output.

As Andrew's comment suggests, you need to unpack the files from the `zip` folder to a regular folder in which you want to create your document. Then from there, open the `.tex` in Texstudio and start working.